# soundEffect from update method keeps looping

Tags: c#, xna

I'am building a game in Xna, and my soundeffects keep looping, it is quite obvious because, the sounds are playing from an update method.

The sounds are not really playing 1 at a time, but like when my car collides to a tile for example named: tile 1, it will play like a 1000+ times at once.

How can I prevent the sound from playing 1000+ times at once, and just make it play 1x at a time?

this is the code I use to play the sound effect:

```
if (map[x][y] == 1)
        {
            car.speed = 0;
            crash.Play();
        }
```

crash is the name of the soundEffect.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: what are you using for the sound engine. Is it XACT?

Answer (score 2):

I would have to recommand to you to read a good tutorial about Xact

You'll think this method is harder than the one you are trying to use, but it's going to be more flexible for you in the futur :)

[Xact on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb203895%28v=xnagamestudio.20%29.aspx)

Or you can use the pause() method from your sound.

Answer (score 0):

Quick example of how you could achieve this:

```
bool soundPlayed = false;   //This would be in a INIT method somewhere

if (map[x][y] == 1)
{
    if (!soundPlayed)
    {
        car.speed = 0;
        crash.Play();
        soundPlayed = true;
    }
}
else
{
    soundPlayed = false;    //Reset once condition is false
}
```

Comment: Make sure you do not put that first line "bool soundplayed = false" at the same location, it should be initialized once before this code is run.

Comment: Yeah, I am did put it in the top code, that only gets executed once. But it doesn't work.